# Unable to get response in controller from model in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and i am using expressjs,I am working on RestApi, Right now my model returns data(from mysql) to controller and i want to display in json format and if i am getting "no data"(nothing from db) then "there is no record " message should display but right i am getting "[object object]",How can i do this ?
Here is my model function

```
static async addServiceDetail(shopId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName)
    {
        /* checking whether same record already exist or not */
        let sql = 'SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE shopId=? AND serviceId=? AND genderTypeId=?';
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute(sql, [shopId, serviceId, genderTypeId]);
        if(rows<1)
            {
                /* Inserting new record into database and getting data according to last isnerted id */
                  const sql2 = `INSERT INTO hc_servicesdetail (shopId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES (?, ?,  ?, ?, ?)`;
                  const values = [shopId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName];
                  const [datass, _] = await pool.execute(sql2, values);
                  var last_inserted_id=datass.insertId;

                    const sql3 = 'SELECT sd.serviceId,sd.genderTypeId,sd.price,s.service_name,s.time FROM hc_servicesdetail sd JOIN services s ON sd.serviceId=s.id WHERE sd.id = ?';
                    const [rows2, fields2] = await pool.execute(sql3,[last_inserted_id]);
                    return rows2;   // GETTING DATA AND TRYING TO RETURN TO CONTROLLER 
            }
        else
            {
                    return false;
            }
    }
}
```

In Console.log i am getting data,Here is my controller function

```
  const service_add = async (req, res) => {
    var shopId=req.body.shopId;
    var serviceId=req.body.serviceId;
    var genderTypeId=req.body.genderTypeId;
    var price=req.body.price;
    var serviceName=req.body.serviceName;
    
    if (!shopId || !serviceId || genderTypeId == null || price == null || !serviceName)
        return res.status(400).send({ statusCode: 400, statusMessage: 'Bad Request', message: null, data: null });
    try 
        {
            const result= await User.addServiceDetail(salonId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName);
            console.log('result is '+ result); // GETTING [object object];
             // want to display data in json format
        } 
        catch (err) 
        {
            //
        }
    res.send("hello worlddd");
}
```